# Create a .gitignore file after creating the repository and publish .idea file?

Tags: git, repository, gitignore, github-actions

I already create a repository in my github account.
But now I want to upload my `idea` file that pycharm created.
That's why I need a `.gitignore`-file.
I know that we created a `gitignore`-file when creating a new repository.
But how can I create a `gitignore`-file after creating and pushing this repository?

Comment: You can both an `.idea` and a `.gitignore` file after creating the repo. Can you elaborate what exactly is the problem?

Comment: You should go back in the history of the project (say, `git rebase -i --root`), amend (edit, in rebase terms) the first revision so that you get the `.gitignore` file in from the get go and also any revision that messes with `.idea` so that those files never show ip in the history of the project.

Answer (score 0):

A `gitignore` file is just a file you can create when you want, that is called "`.gitignore`" (and will list the patterns of files that you **don't** want to add in your repo). If it doesn't exist on your repository, you can create it, commit and push it.
Regardless of the gitignore file,  you can add and commit the `.idea` file since they are not related.

More info on the gitignore file: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

Comment: Adding any IDEs metadata info to any project is a _bad_ idea. Just saying.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, also that, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `.gitignore`-file whenever you want. In several IDE's, if you create and start a new program, by default it already has a `.gitignore`-file where you can add all files, which should not be published after `git push` on your remote repository.

If the repository exists, commits and pushes have been executed include the `.idea`-files, you must *untrack* the `.idea`-files.

With following command, you can removes the file from the repository **without physically deleting**:

```
git rm --cache directory/to/.idea
```

After this command, ignoring should work properly when you commit and push this changes:

```
git commit -m "add gitignore file"
```

```
git push
```

Comment: `git push` only needed when working with git hub not locally, right?